# UISearchBar height on iOS8 when showsScopeBar=YES

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, ios8

I'm using `UISearchBar` in my app, with `showsScopeBar=YES`. When running under iOS8 (both in the simulator and on a device) the scope bar is hidden and the search bar's height remains at 44 instead of the expected 88. Using the new view debugger in Xcode 6 I can see that the scope bar is actually present, but remains hidden behind the text field.

The only way I've found so far is to manually set the search bar's height to 88, which of course is a terrible hack.

Am I missing some documented incompatibility, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I ran into this problem too. After searching on Apples developer forum I found this thread:
https://devforums.apple.com/thread/235803?start=0&tstart=0

And apparently the SearchBar don't automatically does a sizeToFit when it's supposed too. So it's height stays at 44 instead of adjusting to the scope buttons.
The bug is not fixed in the iOS8 GM.

I did a simple [self.searchBar sizeToFit] in my viewWillAppear: and that solved it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this helped a ton! Check out my answer to do it automatically and save you some typing.

Comment: This definitely corrected the search bar,it shows the scope bar properly, but in my case it is hiding the tableview's first row.

Comment: I also checked in the iOS 8 release version.. it fixes the search bar but hiding the tableview's first cell.. Is there anyway to fix it without hiding the tableview's first cell..?

Comment: @user1544494 I was having the same problem as well. Try setting up your searchbar as early as possible, before doing anything else on the tableview itself, that helped in my case

Comment: I got a fix.Refreshing the tableview header like I have mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/a/25970731/1544494 solved the issue.

Comment: Make sure to scroll down to user1544494's answer below, which adds an important piece to the solution.

Answer (score 8):

This issue is occurring in the iOS 8 release version as well.
I added these 2 lines in my viewWillAppear: and that solved it.

`- (void)adjustSearchBarToShowScopeBar{
    [self.searchBar sizeToFit];
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchBar;
}`

Just adding [self.searchBar sizeToFit] was covering up my tableview's first row.
Just refreshing the tableview header fixed the issue perfectly.

Comment: Thanks! Forcing the tableHeader reset is much bettern than having to worry about the order of initialization, particulary when you want to show/hide the scope bar dynamically.

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be not an iOS 8 bug but a Xcode 6 GM compiled Storyboard bug as it happens on iOS 6/7 as well.

As suggested it is fixed by calling `sizeToFit` on the search bar in `viewWillAppear`.

If you want to do it from a view instead of a controller you can try to place it inside `willMoveToWindow`.

---

This bug seems to affect Xcode 5.x builds on iOS 8 and Xcode 6 GM builds on all systems.

Comment: In my case it happens in iOS8 in my apps already in AppStore, built with Xcode 5 and SDK7. And the same App on iSO7 works just fine. So it's a runtime problem in iOS8 and as I understand from the answer on the developer forum I linked to above, it's know by Apple and will probably be fixed in a upcoming iOS8 release.

Comment: Did u guys check in the latest release? I am having this issue which is still there in iOS 8 even when built with iOS 7 SDK.

Comment: Thats the point, the bug is in the OS, not the SDK. So if Your app don't do the sizeToFit call, it will fail on iOS8 but not in iOS7. It doesn't matter which SDK You are using. What Rivera have found is not the same bug.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Janne's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25788774/3422444), I thought it would be helpful to share how to do this automatically with method swizzling.

```
@implementation UISearchBar (iOS8)

static dispatch_once_t dispatchOnceToken;

+ (void)load {
    if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8)
    {
        dispatch_once(&dispatchOnceToken, ^{
            Class class = [self class];

            SEL originalViewWillAppearSelector = @selector(layoutSubviews);
            SEL swizzledViewWillAppearSelector = @selector(swizzled_layoutSubviews);

            Method originalViewWillAppearMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(class, originalViewWillAppearSelector);
            Method swizzledViewWillAppearMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(class, swizzledViewWillAppearSelector);

            if(class_addMethod(class, originalViewWillAppearSelector, method_getImplementation(swizzledViewWillAppearMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(swizzledViewWillAppearMethod)))
            {
                class_replaceMethod(class, swizzledViewWillAppearSelector, method_getImplementation(originalViewWillAppearMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(originalViewWillAppearMethod));
            }
            else
            {
                method_exchangeImplementations(originalViewWillAppearMethod, swizzledViewWillAppearMethod);
            }
        });
    }
}

- (void)swizzled_layoutSubviews
{
    [self swizzled_layoutSubviews];
    [self sizeToFit];
}

@end
```