# iOS9 Scope Bar appears either behind or beside Search Bar

Tags: ios9, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I have a custom `UITableViewController` with a `UISearchController` set to the `tableHeaderView` as follows inside `viewDidLoad()`:

```
    definesPresentationContext = true
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    if #available(iOS 9.1, *) {
        searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    }
    searchController.searchBar.barStyle = .Black
    searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = .Default
    searchController.searchBar.keyboardAppearance = .Dark
    searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = ["Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 3", "Title 3", "Title 3"]
    tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
```

When UITableViewController first loads, the scope bar is visible underneath the search bar and taking the whole width:
[image]

After touching inside the search bar, the scope bar is shown beside the search bar:
[image]

After hitting cancel, the search bar is shown properly without the scope bar underneath, although subsequence touches on the search bar still reveal the scope bar beside it:
[image]

I've tried the following:

- Changing searchBarStyle from .Minimal to .Default
- Calling `sizeToFit()` on `searchBar` and `tableHeaderView`, tried in both viewDidLoad() and viewWillAppear()
- Explicitly setting frame height of `searchBar` and `tableHeaderView` to 88 in `viewWillAppear()`
- The [proposed solutions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25725163/uisearchbar-height-on-ios8-when-showsscopebar-yes/25970731#25970731)
- Purging all builds, cleaning and rebuilding.

Nothing so far has made any difference whatsoever to the appearance or behavior. I want the scope bar below the search bar, and for it not to appear behind the search bar initially. Is `UISearchController` busted or I am just doing something dumb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in UISearchBar, you should create a radar for it.

A workaround is to add some code AFTER you set scopeButtonTitles:

```
UIView *scopeBarContainer = [[[searchController.searchBar.subviews firstObject] subviews] firstObject];
for ( UIView *view in scopeBarContainer.subviews ) {
    if ( [view isKindOfClass:[UISegmentedControl class]] ) {
        scopeBarContainer.hidden = YES;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift :**

```
let scopeBarContainer: UIView? = searchController.searchBar.subviews.first?.subviews.first
if let _ = scopeBarContainer?.subviews.first(where: { $0.isKind(of: UISegmentedControl.self) } ) {
     scopeBarContainer?.isHidden = true
}
```