# iOS Scope Bar does not appear after added under UISearchBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

I added scope bar under my search bar. However, scope bar does not appear. Any idea? Please help.

```
- (UISearchBar *)searchBar{
    if (!_searchBar) {
        _searchBar=[[UISearchBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, kScreenWidth, 24)];
        [_searchBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_searchBar_bgImage"]];
        [_searchBar sizeToFit];
        [_searchBar setPlaceholder:@"Search"];
        [_searchBar.layer setBorderWidth:0.5];
        _searchBar.showsScopeBar = YES;
        _searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"All", @"Near Me", @"Coming Soon", nil];

        [_searchBar.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:229.0/255 green:229.0/255 blue:229.0/255 alpha:1].CGColor];
        [_searchBar setDelegate:self];
        [_searchBar setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeDefault];
        [[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setDefaultTextAttributes:@{
                                                                                                     NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Bitter" size:14],
                                                                                                     }];
    }
    return _searchBar;
}
```

**EDITED:**
I added it in Tableview header. How can I change in order to make it appear?

```
- (UITableView *)tableView{
    if (!_tableView) {
        _tableView=[[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, kScreenWidth, kScreenHeight-49.0) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
        [_tableView setDelegate:self];
        [_tableView setDataSource:self];

        _tableView.tableHeaderView=self.searchBar;

        UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        [_tableView setTableFooterView:v];

    }
    return _tableView;
}
```

Comment: Where did you add `searchBar` to a view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to run your code and scope bar shows up fine for me.

So, while I cannot fathom from code why it should not appear, I would enlist some debugging tips here to help you see what *else* could go wrong that can cause this problem.

While your app is in debug running mode (iOS simulator), try this:

- XCode -> Debug Menu -> View Debugging
- Press Capture View Hierarchy.
- It should come up with a tree structure on the left hand side, showing your table view. On the right hand side it will show you screenshot of your views
- On the left hand side tree, look for the `UISearchbar`.
- Under its hierarchy, search for the object of type: `_UISearchBarScopeBarBackground`. It is followed by `UISegmentedControl` which has segments corresponding to each scope text.

Refer to below image (this should appear in your scope hierarchy):

[image]

- If `UISegmentedControl` appears fine here but not visible on the right side, check to see if its hidden by some other view / table view itself. Some frame adjustment should fix this issue.
- If `UISegmentedControl` does not appear on the left side itself, you seem to have serious problem. Probably your outlets are not initialised and you may want to check if your table view is properly initialised and all. In any case this is very less likely to occur and it's only possible if nothing at all was visible on your simulator screen.

Comment: Thanks Nirav, I didnt see any UISegmentedControl over there. Will further look into it. Thanks for your hints.

Comment: Finally I use separate UISegmentedControl to do as I need it to show permanently.

Comment: strange it did not work. Did you file a radar to Apple? https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/

Comment: Coz I wonder is UISearchbar affected it. Now I applied separate UISegmentedControl and its work!

Comment: Good to know, but it should at least be there even if not showing. You ended up re-inventing the wheel! Did you see this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/25788774/1506363